# Play 2.5 : Troubles with new Result.body type

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to migrate my Play Scala application to the 2.5.0 version but I am blocked at one point.
I have a logging function which runs this :

```
val iterator =  Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], String](""){(acc, v) => acc + new String(v)}
action(request).map{res => 
    val newRes = res.copy()
    newRes.body.run(iterator).foreach(log => Logger.debug(s"\nRequest: ${request.method} ${Routes.service.routeDefinition(request.uri)}\nInput: ${request.body}\nResult: ${newRes}\nOutput: $log"))
    res
}
```

Above, *newRes* is a Result, *body* is an Enumerator[Array[Byte]] and *run* takes an Iteratee.

But now, a Result.body is an HttpEntity and there is no way to get anything of an Enumerator type from the Result class.
Have any of you an idea of how I can do this ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Take a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/StreamsMigration25#Summary-of-changes - Play 2.5 uses Akka Streams as a replacement for Iteratees for streaming

Comment: I'll check that, that seems to be what I need ! Thank you :)